# Howto style a Computed Text field with Pass-Thru turned on

Tags: html, lotus-notes

I have a Computed Text field that has Pass-Thru HTML on it. This field reads a column in a view that is coded to return a URL of a document so the user can open the document.

```
 <a href=“Notes://“+server+”/“+database+”/“+view+”/“+docID+”?opendocument\”>”Link+”</a>”
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to style it. It stays in its default italics, size 10, blue text. What can I do to style it as Ariel, 10 and any other color? This is strictly a client side, not web, app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a ‘style’ tag with ‘a’ at the start of your computed text.

E.g.

```
<style>
   a {color: red}
</style>`
```

Experiment. Quite a lot of css is supported. As long as it can be ‘translated’ by Notes to RichText.

Comment: Thanks Theo. Why is it that the obvious way is always the hardest to remember?